# C++ Problems with destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a problem and I don't know the solution for it, need you help! Thank you in advance!

Here my class (class is copied not completely)

```
#ifndef _CGRAPH_H_
#define _CGRAPH_H_


class Cgraph{

typedef std::list<int> vlist;
typedef std::map<int, int > vidmap;
typedef std::map<int, std::string > vutfmap;
typedef std::map<int, vlist > vmap;
typedef std::map<int, vlist >::iterator vmap_it;

int frequency;


private:

    vidmap vertices;
    vutfmap utf;
    vmap wattackedges; // label 0
    vmap battackedges; // label 1
    vmap defendedges_label2; 
    vmap defendedges_label3;

    vmap bdefendedges_label2; 
    vmap bdefendedges_label3;


    std::string eLine(int, int, int);
    std::string vLine(int, int);


public:



    Cgraph(){   
    };
    ~Cgraph(){ delete &vertices;
           delete &utf; delete &wattackedges; delete &battackedges;
           delete &defendedges_label2; delete &defendedges_label3;
           delete &bdefendedges_label2; delete &bdefendedges_label3;};
```

in the main methode I do following

```
Cgraph *graph = new Cgraph();
delete graph;
```

and I get this error report

```
*** Error in `./chess': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffffebb1340 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `delete &vertices` You haven't allocated them with `new` - you have no business deallocating them with `delete`. Drop all those `delete` statements - they are nonsense. You don't appear to need a user-defined destructor at all (nor default constructor, for that matter).

Comment: Literally delete your entire destructor. Problem solved.

Comment: A destructor should undo the actions of the constructor. Your constructor is empty, so your destructor should be empty, too.

Comment: If C++ required to call `delete` on all the member variables, I would quit and use Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never explicitly dynamically allocated those members with `new` so you shouldn't be `delete`ing them. Since those members all have destructors that'll take care of cleanup, you don't need your destructor.

Answer (score 0):

map will have internally created the memory required for it and when the destroctor is called the destructor of map also will be called and clears all data.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/~map/